# Why isn't this assignment raising an error in TS?

Tags: typescript

Can somebody explain to me why assignment for *n* isn't raising an error or warning in TS? `n` is a number type and `obj` is anything but a number, not logic found.

```
let obj: any = { x: 0 };
const n: number = obj;
console.log(n);
```

Output:

```
{ x: 0 }
```

---

### CONCLUSION

According to the answers given here I can deduce that any variable with a defined type that interacts with another variable of type ANY will behave as if it were also of type ANY.

This is strange to me because the same code written in Dart would be:

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  dynamic obj = (x:1);
  int n = obj;
  print(n);
}
```

Output:

```
Unhandled exception:
type '({int x})' is not a subtype of type 'int'
#0      main
demo.dart:3
#1      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:294:33)
#2      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)
```

This makes more sense to me.

Comment: you have give obj the `any` type

Comment: `any` effectively means *I know better than you* to the compiler

Comment: Shouldn't `n` check the correct type assigned to it because it can accept numbers only unlike `obj`? that's my confusion. that assignment seems like some kind of cheat

Answer (score 2):

In short, when you use the `any` type on your variable can be assigned to literally `any`thing. You essentially opt-out of type checking and tell the TypeScript compiler to represent values without any constraints.

From the official [TypeScipt docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any):

> TypeScript also has a special type, `any`, that you can use whenever you
> don’t want a particular value to cause typechecking errors.
>
> When a value is of type `any`, you can access any properties of it
> (which will in turn be of type `any`), call it like a function, assign
> it to (or from) a value of any type, or pretty much anything else
> that’s syntactically legal.

---

Another way to look at it is `number extends anything` for example, this is true thus the assignment is valid which is the reason you don't get a compiler error in your particular example. However, you might run into runtime errors when performing number actions on your variable. TypeScript only infers `n` as a `number` but the actual value is your object.

E. g.

```js
let obj: any = {x: 0};
let n: number = obj;
n.toExponential();
//^
//TypeError: n.toExponential is not a function
```

Comment: I've added a conclusion to my question

Comment: Please post a new question. All of a sudden you switched to totally different programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Since obj has the `any` type, it can be assigned to variable of any type.

`any` type is like telling the compiler that you do not know the type. So it can be anything and can be assigned to variables of any type.

`any` can be used for migrating projects from JavaScript to TypeScript, and assign `any` to most variables first.

**Update for OP's conclusion**

dynamic in Dart is more like inferred type (not explicitly declaring type) in TypeScript.
If that makes more sense to you, you can remove the number type for n.

```
let obj = { x: 0 };
const n = obj;
```

and this will raise an error.

Comment: I've added a conclusion to my question

Comment: I have edited in response to the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

About your confusion in the Conclusion:

In Typescript, the type check doesn't happen in Runtime (like Dart as I understood from your example). and that is because Typescript code will be transpiled (compiled) into JavaScrip (which doesn't have types) before getting executed.

The type check in TS happens while transpiling only.

Answer (score 0):

As other comments mentioned already, having `any` is like suspending type-checking for that variable/constant, so you can use it anywhere as anything!

IMO: a perfect code shouldn't have any `any` in it.

Comment: "IMO: a perfect code shouldn't have any any in it." is an opinion and is usually best left to the asker to decide.

Comment: "IMO" literally means "IN MY OPINION", so yes it is an opinion, not a fact (I think your comment is redundant)

Comment: I've added a conclusion to my question

Comment: I wrote you another answer :) hopefully it is helpful